# How to send simulated remote notification to iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 11.4 introduced sending simulated push notification on iOS simulator

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answering my own question :P

Requirement: **Xcode 11.4 beta or above**

## Method 1, Online tool

Use online tool to test push notifications, I personally found it more useful than methods below, it's more straightforward and does not require remembering `simctl` command

Website: http://pushplayground.com/

## Method 2, Command line

There are 2 ways, both needed a JSON file with a valid Apple Push Notification Service payload (with .apns extension)

Example apns: (Save it as XXX.apns file)

```
{
    "aps":{
        "alert":"Test",
        "sound":"default",
        "badge":1
    }
}
```

Using `simctl` to send simulated notification

```
$ xcrun simctl push <SIMULATOR_DEVICE_ID> <YOUR_APP_BUNDLE_ID> <APNS_FILE_NAME>
```

Usage:

```
$ xcrun simctl push A0AF405F-FE73-45DA-8D7D-F1FE37821992 com.example.my-app test.apns
```

You can find the simulator device id with

```
xcrun simctl list
```

Example:
[image]

## Method 3, Drag and Drop apns file to simulator

When using drag and drop, you apns file needed to include a key that indicates your app bundle id

Key name: `Simulator Target Bundle`

Value: `Your app bundle id`
Example:

```
{
    "Simulator Target Bundle": "YOUR_APP_BUNDLE_ID",
    "aps":{
        "alert":"Test",
        "sound":"default",
        "badge":1
    }
}
```

After that, simply drag and drop the file into the simulator, and voilà!
[image]